# How to count the number of children when the name of it is known simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

i'm trying to count the number of children of a parent in an xml with SimpleXML and i know the name of child to count.How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code then only we give a better answer for you

Comment: Quite a lot of your questions are showing no research at all, and are attracting downvotes/closevotes as a result. Please read the Help section here before posting, and bear in mind that too many closed questions will start to automatically prevent you from asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$xml` is the simple XML variable name

**parent** is the name of the parent node

**children** is the name of the children node

```
echo  count($xml->parent->children);
```

Answer (score 0):

From PHP 5.3+ you can use [`SimpleXMLElement::count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php)

Or

```
$sXML= new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$child = $sXML->children();
echo count($child);
```

Comment: Actually, the code you see there is the version that worked *before* PHP 5.3. Also, as a nitpick, just an opinion, but this is a really bad name for a variable: `$child = $sXML->children()`.

Comment: @IMSoP Alright. 'L tak care..:)